# contextily.add_basemap() is not using correct extend of axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, contextily

I want create a matplotlib figure with two subplots of which one is a map. To add a basemap I use contextily. The axis ratio should be `aspect="equal"` and to ensure that both subplots nonetheless have the same height I set `adjustable="datalim"` for this axis. This works fine, but contextily does not seem to pick up this change of the axis limits and adds the basemap only to a part of the subplot.

I have prepared this minimal example:

```
import contextily as cx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=2)

axes[0].plot([0,1],[0,1],marker="o")
axes[1].plot([7.60,11.13],[51.81,52.10]) 
axes[1].set(aspect="equal", adjustable="datalim")

cx.add_basemap(axes[1],crs="EPSG:4326")
```

which produces the following plot:
[image: minimal example output]

Answer (score 0):

> To ensure that both subplots have the same height I set aspect="equal"

This  is not true... the aspect-ratio determines the scale between the x- and y- axis... not the relation between axes in a figure!

If you want the subplots to share the plot-extent, use

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
```

for further info, see

- [mpl aspect example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html)
- [mpl shared axes example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html)

---

**Update**

OK, after your comment I think I get your problem... you want both axes to have the same height while the right axes has to maintain aspect-ratio to avoid image distortions, and in addition you want the right axes to have "tight" limits (e.g. showing only the image without margins)

Using `adjustable="datalim"` causes the margin and there is no way to avoid this. What you actually want is to use `adjustable="box"` and then set the axes size to match the desired data limits.

To do that you have to evaluate the desired aspect-ratio and set the axis-position accordingly. The following lines should do the job:

```py
import contextily as cx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 3), nrows=1,ncols=2)

ax0.plot([0,1],[0,1],marker="o")
ax1.plot([7.60,11.13],[51.81,52.10]) 
ax1.set(aspect="equal", adjustable="box")

bbox0 = ax0.get_position()
bbox1 = ax1.get_position()
aspect = bbox1.width / bbox1.height
ax1.set_position((bbox1.x0, bbox0.y0, bbox0.height * aspect, bbox0.height))

cx.add_basemap(ax1, crs="EPSG:4326", zoom=4)
```

This will result in a figure looking somewhat like this since your map extent is extremely wide... (e.g. you'd need to make the first axes quite small to have them next to each other)

[image]

...since the constant re-shuffling of axes (especially together with geo-axes) can be quite tedious, I recommend that you also have a look at the package I'm developing :-D  ([EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)) which provides a basic [LayoutEditor](https://eomaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_layout_editor.html) to ease the pain of re-arranging axes and maps in a figure...
The corresponding code would then look somewhat like this:

```py
from eomaps import Maps

m = Maps(ax=122)
m.set_extent((7.60,11.13, 51.81,52.10), 4326)
m.add_wms.OpenStreetMap.add_layer.stamen_terrain()
m.ax.plot([7.60,11.13],[51.81,52.10], marker="o") 

ax = m.f.add_subplot(121)
ax.plot([0,1],[0,1],marker="o")

layout = {
    "figsize": [12.0, 2.0],
    "0_map": [0.1675, 0.345, 0.81149, 0.4],
    "1_": [0.0375, 0.345, 0.0975, 0.4],
}
m.apply_layout(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I needed to put `aspect="equal"` because the subplot is a map and it would distort the map if the axis ratio is not equal. `adjustable="datalim"` allows the axis to adjust its datalimits, so that it can still have the same heigth as the other subplot.
`sharey=True` is not an option because the axes neither have the same unit nor the same scale.
I will edit my post and correct this.

Comment: Hey @Tobias, I updated the answer accordingly... hope that helps now...